# Electron: How to create a new BrowserWindow according to the closed event of the last window?

Tags: node.js, events, electron

There are two BrowserWindow instances, and browser2 will create according to browser1 closing. The question is that the closed event of browser1 propagates and impacts browser2. How can I prevent the closed event to impact browser2 even though browser2 is listening the closed event?

Demo is following:

```
let browser1 = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
  })

browser1.on('closed', (e) => {
      let browser2 = BrowserWindow({
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
      })
      browser2.on('closed', (e) => {
        console.log("browser2 received closed event")
      }
})
```

Comment: Hey, did my answer work for you?

Comment: @Joshua Of course ! As you said, browser2 creating need to be put into the "close" event of the browser1.  By the way, sorry to say that I don't have enough reputations even though I want upvote your answer very much, and once I have 15+ reputations, I'll remember to upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `close` event rather than the `closed` event.

- [`close`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#event-close): Triggered while the window is still open, and is about to be closed.
- [`closed`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#event-closed): Triggered after the window is closed.

Like this:

```
browser1.on('close', (e) => {
```

Instead of:

```
browser1.on('closed', (e) => {
```

---

<sup>PS: your second `BrowserWindow` is missing the `new` keyword like this: ` = new BrowserWindow`, and the 2nd `closed` event is missing a closing `)`.</sup>

Comment: @PaulYu Perfect, make sure to accept my answer by clicking the green check mark. Also, upvote my answer because it'll give me more points :)

Comment: Sorry to say that I don't have enough reputations even though I want to upvote your answer very much, and once I have 15+ reputations, I'll remember to upvote it.